# Python OOP .txt file import not working as expected

Tags: python-2.7, oop, object

I'm trying to import the first 6 lines of a .txt file into a collection of objects:

```
 from Header import Header

class HeaderReader(list):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HeaderReader, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def headerCreator(filePath):
        with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
            headerHolder = HeaderReader()

            for line in file:
                splittedEls = line.split('\n')
                if len(splittedEls) != 6:
                    continue
                header = Header(
                    splittedEls[0],
                    splittedEls[1],
                    splittedEls[2],
                    splittedEls[3],
                    splittedEls[4],
                    splittedEls[5]
                )
                headerHolder.append(header)

            return headerHolder
```

Header is a object with 6 atributes, the first 6 lines of the .txt file is divided by line (\n) after that there is other content, I think the problem is probably in the `if len(splittedEls) != 6:`but I'm not sure if it is or how to resolve it. Also it might be a error to define a class, give it a `__init__` then call a staticmethod. When i pass it on a .txt file it return a empty list. Any ideas?

Comment: You are iterating over **each line** in the file.  It is quite impossible for a single line to contain six newlines!  Either call ``.readlines()`` on the file to get a list of lines (note: each one will include a newline at the end, except possibly the last), or ``.read()`` to read the whole file into a string that you can ``.split()``.

Comment: So if i just remove the added '\n' wouldn't that fix it? Other then that, what i did with the super and static method is fine?